# Unresolved external symbol C++ - wrong declaration?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, external

I'm having problem writing a class.
The problem ocurred whEN I moved the definition to ANother source file to stay "clean".

The message I receive is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: 1 projekt - sklep, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
.1funkcje.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class Rachunek Kasa_sklepowa" .(?Kasa_sklepowa@@3VRachunek@@A)
1>metody_r.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class Rachunek Kasa_sklepowa" .(?Kasa_sklepowa@@3VRachunek@@A)

1>C:\Users\Ja\Desktop\Studia\PW\Semestr II\C++\Cwiczenia - klasy,obiekty\Debug\1 projekt - .sklep.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

where `Kasa_Sklepowa` is an object I declared as A global in main.cpp - 
I guEss this may be a reason why there's something wrong.

Before it had been showing me that there is something wrong in the class dclaration with string.

```
#pragma once

class Rachunek
{
double saldo_ogolne;
public:
    Rachunek() {saldo_ogolne=0;};
    ~Rachunek();
    void transakcja(std::string,std::string,double);
    void czysc_zarobki();
};
```

A source file (cpp)

```
extern Rachunek Kasa_sklepowa;
void Rachunek::transakcja(string _pes,string co,double ile)
{ 
     bla bla
     }
```

The main file

```
Rachunek Kasa_sklepowa();
int main (int agc, char**argv)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Why would you need "extern Rachunek Kasa_sklepowa;" in class impl file ? Also you have to include the "Rachunek.h" file inside main.cpp.

Comment: And it looks like you are using MSVC, pls add Rachunek.h/.cpp files to your project.

Comment: I've included Rachunek.h in the main file.
I have to have this "extern .." because then I have errors like
>1>c:\users\ja\desktop\studia\pw\semestr ii\c++\cwiczenia - klasy,obiekty\1 projekt - sklep\metody_r.cpp(71): error C2065: 'Kasa_sklepowa' : undeclared identifier
They have been added to my project.
Do you want me to paste them here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
Rachunek Kasa_sklepowa();
```

declares a function, which is different from a variable.

What you need to do is write this line in the same header as the Rachunek class:

```
extern Rachunek Kasa_sklepowa;
```

And in the corresponding .cpp file, write:

```
Rachunek Kasa_sklepowa;
```

The first line just declares so that it's visible to the compiler, the second one actually defines it so that it's placed in the .obj file and is visible to the linker.

BTW, a better way is to use a static variable:

```
class Rachunek
{
public:
    static Rachunek Kasa_sklepowa;

    ...
```

And in the .cpp file, write:

```
Rachunek Rachunek::Kasa_sklepowa;
```

Comment: OK, 2 errors less :)
There's only one left


1>funkcje.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class Rachunek Kasa_sklepowa" (?Kasa_sklepowa@@3VRachunek@@A)
1>C:\Users\Ja\Desktop\Studia\PW\Semestr II\C++\Cwiczenia - klasy,obiekty\Debug\1 projekt - sklep.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Maybe you didn't add the Rachunek implementation file (.cpp) to your project.

Comment: I have added
You know.. notice that now error points on funkcje.obj and in funkcje.cpp I have 

extern Rachunek Kasa_sklepowa;

Maybe it has to do with it?

Comment: Do you have `extern Rachunek Kasa_sklepowa;` in the header, or in the .cpp file? It should be in the header. In the .cpp file you need `Rachunek Kasa_sklepowa;` (without **extern**).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the extern declaration on the cpp file.

Regarding the string-related error you encountered previously - make sure you `#import <string>`.

Comment: String is OK.
The funny thing is that i only moved the "transakcja" function from one file to another and nothing else :(